# Returning value in new column based on other columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to mirror vlookup function into python script:

If value from GPN column in analysis_sheet is in GPN column in whitelist_sheet I want to return value from column SOURCE in whitelist_sheet DataFrame to column RCL in analysis_sheet. Here are some of my trials, but non worked:

```
analysis_sheet['RCL'] = analysis_sheet['GPN'].isin(whitelist_sheet['GPN'])
```

and

```
analysis_sheet['RCL'] = ((analysis_sheet['GPN'].loc[analysis_sheet['GPN'].isin(whitelist_sheet['GPN']), analysis_sheet['RCL']]) = whitelist_sheet['SOURCE'])
```

and

```
analysis_sheet['RCL'] = analysis_sheet.merge(whitelist_sheet, right_on='SOURCE')
```

and

```
analysis_sheet['RCL'] = analysis_sheet.loc[analysis_sheet['GPN'].isin(whitelist_sheet['GPN']), whitelist_sheet['SOURCE']]
```

Here is example how it should work:
[RESULT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5b9k.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'GPN': [111, 222, 333, 444], 'col2': ['fsgd', 'sdg', 'sfgf', 'sfgf'], 'col3':['bgg', 'gd', 'gbg', 'gbg']}
analysis_sheet = pd.DataFrame(data1)  
data2 = {'GPN': [111, 222, 333, 555], 'col2': ['as', 'df', 'dd', 'sd'], 'Source':['HH', 'BB', 'CD', 'GK']}
whitelist_sheet = pd.DataFrame(data2).rename(columns={'col2': 'to_be_droped'}) 
analysis_sheet.merge(whitelist_sheet, on=['GPN'], how='left').rename(columns={'Source': 'RCL'}).drop('to_be_droped', axis=1)
```